# How to detect add or subtract 1 hour for daylight saving in momentJS

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, dst, timezone-offset

I'm using momentJS to handle date and times in my application. All the datetime specific fields are being saved in the database as UTC format. At the time of rendering these dates, I use UTC Offset (-8.00 etc.) in momentJS like below:

```
moment(utcDate).utcOffset(-8.00).format()
```

This gives me the Pacific Time only in case of no daylight saving. But we talk about today's date, the above is not correct becasue we must have to add `1 hour` of daylight saving in the offset hence it becomes `-07.00`.

But my problem is, how to detect and add this 1 hour in moment.

I tried `moment(date).utcOffset(-8.00).isDST()` which gives false all the time so not sure how to handle it.

Comment: For all your timezone needs ... moemntjs has a library for that as well https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: The problem is I have only offset at this moment. So is it not possible using that only?

Comment: I don't understand - momentjs timezone will give you the tools necessary to solve the issue of `how to detect` that you can't solve - look at the documentation for timezone to understand how to use it

Comment: @RobG thank you for the lesson I didn't need

Comment: Offsets aren't timezones, you can't reliably determine if a place observes daylight saving or not just from the offset. There are many places that have the same standard offset, but some observe daylight saving and others do not. Only the administrative area that the location falls in will tell you that (which is why [*IANA timezones*](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) use geographical locations like Africa/Lagos).

Comment: @JaromandaX—fair cop, comment redirected.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this particular problem? If so please share (you can also self answer your question).

Comment: No I haven't yet. I guess, I will have make use of timezone strings instead of UTC offset vaues